# Fracctionate turtles population in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

Hello I am writing a code in which a population of turtles with 3 different colors interact and play certain strategies with a payoff from using any of the strategy. But what i want to do is create a population of turtles and fractionate it to get, let say, 1/3 with color blue, 1/3 with color red and 1/3 with color green but without using 3 buttons just defining the population like number with a slider. Any suggestions for the code?

Answer (score 2):

If you want exactly one third in each color, the following will work (and has the advantage of automatically dealing with the case where the slider value is not divisible by 3):

```
create-turtles <slider varname>
[ ...
  set color item (who mod 3) (list red blue green)
...
]
```

If you want a more probabilistic approach, where each turtle has a chance of being any of the colors (and potentially different group sizes), it's almost the same code

```
create-turtles <slider varname>
[ ...
  set color one-of (list red blue green)
...
]
```

Comment: I was about the write a very similar answer, except that I'd use [`one-of`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#one-of) instead of `item (random 3)`.

Comment: For that matter, I'd also `let colors [red green blue]` and then use `length colors` instead of writing `3` directly.

Comment: Changed to do your first comment, which is clearly the better approach - I had started to do the normal approach for unequal probabilities and then realised it was equal and switched but hadn't got rid of the 'random' from my brain.

Comment: Thank you so much for the code, really help me a lot, now i can continue with my program